# Any app to manage a servers and remote console?

Tags: datacenter, ipmi, ilo, drac, manage

I can't find a software to manage servers, connect to remote console, reboot, power cycle, see temperatures etc, only if I enter by the management IP and one by one server.

iDRAC, iLO are also part of the infraestructure.

Anyone knows how can I do that? Any tool to consolidate servers?

Thanks

Comment: We don't do shopping or product recommendation questions here. - http://serverfault.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Dell and HP both offer a free product to manage their servers in bulk. Dell's is called OpenManage Essentials, and HP's is called Systems Insight Manager.